# C# Remoting Register a class from Host App as service

Tags: c#, remoting, .net-remoting

I am developing a solution to run on local network.

I have successfully created a dummy solution that hosts a assembly dll as a service (using Remoting) in a WinForms application and listens to the client communication through proxy object.

Now I need to extend the functionality of the service so that it can perform more complex operations which will be part of the Host App, for this reason I tried registering service from a local class and this is where I hit a dead-end, it is throwing ArgumentNullException.

I have two questions:

1. Is it even possible to register a class from an executable app as a service? If yes, what is the correct procedure?
2. If no, then how can the assembly dll further notify the Host App of the data recieved?

P.S : I am new to C#. Please excuse any stupid mistakes.

EDIT:

The requirement is for one way communication only. Would WCF still be the best way to proceed?

Comment: In 2018 you are building software with Remoting? IMO, that is your mistake. Can you reboot and go with Web API?

Comment: *"I am new to C#"* Then please don't start with outdated technology. Ditch WinForms and Remoting.

Comment: Go for WPF + WCF (or WebAPI as Crowcoder suggested) From MSDN: [*"This topic is specific to a legacy technology that is retained for backward compatibility with existing applications and is not recommended for new development. Distributed applications should now be developed using the  Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)."*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72x4h507(v=vs.100).aspx) (And even that hint is ~7 years old!)

Comment: @Manfred : Actually I tried WCF too. I am trying to extend an application which supports COM/ActiveX objects. That is where I left the WCF and went in other direction. I will try it again with WPF! Thanks for guidance.

Comment: @Crowcoder : Did not know about Web API. Will look into it as well..Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: WCF service is up and running.But the same issue exists, cannot get the target application to create an object from the ActiveX DLL(Client) to consume the service. I will ask a new question for that.